# Compare 2 tables in MsExcel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry, Here is an additional question:

I have 2 tables with large amount of data:
 Example -

```
table 1:

Course code   Region
100201-200    New York 
100201-210    New York
100201-220    New York
101201-300    Los Angeles
101201-310    Los Angeles
101201-320    Los Angeles
101201-330    Los Angeles
102201-400    San Diego
102201-410    San Diego
102201-420    San Diego

...........
```

table 2 (table 2 contains many fields - doesn't matter what's inside)

```
Course Code  Course Date  Course Time etc...........
100201-200   ....................................... 
100201-210
101201-300    ......................................
101201-320
```

I need to compare "table 2" against "table 1" and find Course Code from "table 2" which matches Course Code in "table 1" to display what Region from "table 1" associated with "table 2".

Do I have to use vlookup function in MsExcel?
If yes, how exactly...?

Huge thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `VLOOKUP`.  Here is the syntax for it:

```
VLOOKUP( value, table_array, index_number, [not_exact_match] )
```

Have a look at the examples here on [MSDN VLOOKUP Manual Page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

See also:

[Function: HLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/hlookup-function-HA102752997.aspx?CTT=1), [Function: LOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/lookup-function-HP010342671.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342670), [Excel Lookup Functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/lookup-and-reference-functions-reference-HP010342670.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: To: Ahmed Masud - My problem.... When I use vlookup I look cell like A2, A3, A4 etc. - which should dynamically change..but the array should stay constant - like A2:C6655.  How do I copy vlookup so that the 1st cell in my formula would change but the array would stay the same?